# How to filter results using wildcard in linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to list the contents of /usr/bin having "ab" in their names.

I wrote the following command:

ls /usr/bin *ab*

But it didn't work.

Is there any other command that can be used to achieve my purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: Basic questions about interactive use of the shell are not really suitable for Stack Overflow, which is for _programming_ questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

```sh
ls /usr/bin *ab*
```

asks `ls` to list *two* things: the contents of the `/usr/bin` directory **as well as** any files matching the wildcard `*ab*` in your current directory. If there aren't any files matching `*ab*` in your current directory, there's probably an error message before or after the listing of /usr/bin; if there are such files, they'll be listed. Instead, you want:

```sh
ls /usr/bin/*ab*
```

... which asks your shell to give `ls` the expanded list of files in /usr/bin that match the wildcard.